# Are there any topics on Procedural Generation based on a predefined mesh?

Tags: procedural-generation

I see a lot of post about procedural terrain generation, but this is not what I'm looking for. **I want procedural generation**, but I want to be able to **define** the **shape** of the generation based on a **predefined mesh** so that I can modify the mesh at run-time. Say I hit armor with a sword, the armor takes damage and the mesh is modified based on the sharpness of the sword, at the exact location (ex: vertices, chunks) on the armor where the sword hit.

Edit: To make the question a little less general. How would one go about modifying a predefined mesh using procedural generation. If that's too broad to introduce here, where has this been done before in games?

I've spent quite a few hours searching Google for this type of technique but its hard to find  what I'm looking for as I am inexperienced in the subject.

I've looked at marching cubes and marching tetrahedrons but I'm not really sure if that's what I'm looking for. those techniques seem to send back a quality not really acceptable for a video game. Meta-balls look nice but they seem to be only suitable for liquids. And as I said earlier, random terrain generation or pseudo-random based on seeds is definitely not what I'm looking for. I need to be able to control the mesh enough to reliably create and modify objects. IE, carve a Z in your armor if at runtime

Comment: Questions asking for lists of resources aren't on topic (too broad). It sounds like what you're asking for is a method to *deform* pre-created meshes (armor) according to certain criteria rather than to *generate* any sort of mesh?

Comment: I will delete the question then if it is not allowed. But to answer your question, yes that is essentially what I want the end result to be.

Comment: This question might still be fine with some edits to highlight what you need specifically, rather than being a general call for resources.

Comment: Quite honestly, it sounds like you're looking for destructible mesh rather than a procedurally generated one. You aren't generating a new piece of armor, you're deforming an existing one. Unfortunately, there still doesn't seem to be a lot of documentation surrounding it. Guess there's a reason it's still a selling point for AAA games, eh?

Comment: Well, the armor thing was just one example. I also wanted to be able to create the meshes at runtime via the user, hence procedural generation. I'll be closing the topic in about 10-15 minutes as it really is too broad.

Comment: I can't delete the question, maybe Josh can as he is a moderator? I'll flag it.

Comment: @Courie deletion is generally frowned upon, and usually done only if the content is actually harmful, like spam. This one might be useful as you've accepted an answer, but even if not, we prefer to close questions rather than delete them, as it helps future visitors know what's not on topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many of such methods exist. Though typically their in mesh editing programs, such as Blender 3D. For example, the "Boolean" modifier, allows you to intersect, subtract, or add, on one mesh volume, based on another mesh volume.

Going through a modeling program, and learning how to manually do it in that program would be a good first step to doing what you want. Then figuring out how that program does it, (eg. going through the blender source code and looking through the code of the Boolean modifier.) Then actually creating your own implementation.

An example program outline might be:

1. Grab the meshfilters for the armor mesh, and the sword mesh, including object transformations, and velocity vectors.
2. Enter processing loop

   - Early out based vertex-position and vertex-normals to decide which vertices could not possibly be hit. (Eg, you don't need to process the left shoulder if the right shoulder is the one that gets hit. Just copy it over into your new "generated" mesh.)
   - Triangle intersection tests, to determine the volume being removed from the armor.
   - Continue until the entire mesh has been appropriately processed.
3. Do one of the fallowing:

   - Delete the triangles within the volume calculated by step 2, and generate new triangles to replace them based on the given information.
   - Modify the vertices within the volume calculated by step 2, based on the given information.
4. finalize the changes
5. cleanup any temporary resources

However, creating such detailed meshes can become **very** costly. Especially if you are doing that every few frames, it ties up your CPU with generating the mesh, and your GPU with having to load the data off of your RAM and process the extra vertices.

Typically what is done is a simple decal applied to the mesh. Then you only pass a few vectors to the GPU telling it where to put the "scratch" decal, and it get's done quickly.

Edit: This still isn't really a complete answer. But it's the best I could do. There would be to much information to cover for a complete explanation.